# Can I force Windows Server DNS to forward queries to DHCP server when the client/DHCP domain matches AD domain?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory

I currently have a Windows Server 2k19 host operating as a domain controller with integrated DNS. Clients joined to the domain use this DNS server. I have a separate Linux host operating as the DHCP server for the entire network, and it has its own DNS server. Non-domain clients connect to this DNS server. The DHCP server's domain name is the same as that of the Active Directory, so all clients on the network can be accessed as client.addomain.com.

The DC is configured to use the Linux DNS server as its only alternate, and it properly forwards all non-domain queries to the DNS server. However, it does not forward anything on .addomain.com, even if it can't resolve it. This means that any client on the Linux DNS server can resolve all client names, but any client on the Windows DNS server can only resolve client names on the Windows DNS server.

I've tried every manner of forwarding, but nothing seems to work. Is there a way to make Windows Server 2k19 forward *.addomain.com requests when it can't resolve them itself?

Comment: I know that I can solve the problem by rearchitecting (e.g. make the DC my DHCP server as well), but I'm interested in solutions that don't require me to move services.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how DNS works in Linux, but Windows DNS won't forward queries that result in NXDOMAIN to another DNS server for DNS zones that the Windows DNS server is authoritative for.

Comment: Well... that's exactly what I'm trying to do. Is there a way to reconfigure Windows DNS such that its not authoritative for the AD domain?

Comment: Delete the DNS zone from the Windows server. Create the needed DNS records for AD on the Linux DNS server. Configure DHCP on the Linux server to assign itself as DNS server for all DHCP clients.